# equation with quadratic power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking how to solve:

- If $x^{(x-1)^2}=2x+1$, find $x-\frac{1}{x}$
- Solve $x^{x-x^2+13} = x^2-12$

I noticed that in both problems, the linear part can be constructed in the quadratic exponent, I tried a few change of variable and nothing.

Comment: ok, for first poblem $x=1+\sqrt{2}$. For the second $x=3, x=4$ by inspection.

Comment: I think you mean $-3$, not $3$.

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI yeah, missed the minus sign haha

Comment: @user134338 what do you think of my solution?

Comment: also, what bothers me about Problem $1$ is that $x=1-\sqrt{2}$ is actually also a solution.

Comment: which makes one wonder that the problem is not as naive as simply solving that equation, but rather, it involves some tricks with $x-\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI definitivally  has some trick with $x-1/x$. I tried $x-1/x = 2 $ and look for some trick and nothing still. I like your solution, its very smart!!

Comment: thank you! But here's an observation for $1$: The solutions are actually equivalent to solving the equation: $x^2-2x-1=0$.

Comment: so we have to reduce the problem 1 to this equation

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI i solved, check my answer. I use your method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible approach to the second problem:

Observe that $x-x^2+13=-(x^2-12)+x+1$, so let $a=x^2-12$.

Now, we wish to solve the equation $x^{-a+x+1}=a$. Note that $x=0$ is not a solution; this is by inspection.

It is easy to see that $x=a$ actually satisfies the preceding equation. Now, we argue that all other values of $x$ does not work:

$x>a \Rightarrow x-a >0 \Rightarrow x-a+1>1 \Rightarrow x^{x-a+1}>a^{x-a+1} >a \ \forall \ x$, if $x \in \mathbb{R^+}$.  So, equality does not hold.

Likewise, $x<a \Rightarrow x-a <0 \Rightarrow x-a+1<1 \Rightarrow x^{x-a+1}<a^{x-a+1} <a \ \forall \ x$, if $x \in \mathbb{R^+}$, and $x-a+1 \geq 0$. Otherwise, if $x-a+1<0$, $ x^{x-a+1}>a^{x-a+1} >a$. So equality never happens.

Thus, given that $x=a$, we have $x^2-12=x \Rightarrow (x+4)(x+3)=0 \Rightarrow x=4$ or $ x=-3$, and these are the two solutions to our equation, so we are done.

Comment: it is very clever !

Comment: @ONG SEE HAI HCI  $-3$ is not root, by the domain. The domain is $x>0$.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Following the method of [ONG SEE HAI HCI](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3601874)  , we have $A = 2x+1$
then:

$$x^{(x-1)^2}=x^{x^2+2-(2x+1)}=2x+1$$
then $x^{x^2+2-A} = A $ with only solution $x=\sqrt{A}$.

This is because $x^{x^2+2-A}$ is increasing.

Then $x=\sqrt{A} \rightarrow x^2 = 2x+1 \rightarrow x = 2+ \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow x-\frac{1}{x} = 2$

Comment: I am sorry, is it obvious that it's increasing?

Comment: this is because its equal to $x^{(x-1)^2}$

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI same argument can be used for your answer

Comment: I see your point now.

Answer (score 1):

A hint to the first problem.

Prove that for $x\geq2$ the function $f(x)=(x-1)^2\ln{x}-\ln(2x+1)$ increases.

Indeed, for $x\geq2$ we obtain:
$$f'(x)=2(x-1)\ln{x}+\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}-\frac{2}{2x+1}>0.$$

Thus, since $f(2)<0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty,$

we see that our equation has an unique root on $[2,+\infty).$

Now, easy to check that $1+\sqrt2$ is a root.

Indeed, $$(1+\sqrt2)^{(1+\sqrt2-1)^2}-2(1+\sqrt2)-1=(1+\sqrt2)^2-3-2\sqrt2=0.$$

The second equation we can solve by the similar way. I got that $4$ is a root.

Comment: I got uniqueless of root between 2 and 3 byother argumetns. But how you got $1+\sqrt{2}$ algebraically?

Comment: @user134338 I added something. See now.

Comment: that is verification, but how you known that $1+\sqrt{2}$ will be useful?

Comment: that's interesting, why is the answer for the first problem equals to 2?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI I got 2 graphically with program

Comment: @ONG SEE HAI HCI Because $1+\sqrt2-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt2-(\sqrt2-1)=2.$

Comment: but i don't understand why 1+srqt(2) is a solution of the equation.

Comment: @user134338 See please my post. I proved that for $x>2$ there is an unique root of the equation.

Comment: @ONG SEE HAI HC See please my post. I proved it.

Comment: You proved uniqueless of solution, and then the value $1+\sqrt{2}$ appears magically solving the equation. How does you think on   $1+\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: But, as what @user134338 mentioned earlier, how did you even arrive at 1+$\sqrt(2)$ in the first place? It seems like a  mysterious number that popped out of nowhere

Comment: @Luis Felipe I saw an expression $(x-1)^2$ and I thought about $1\pm\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is a natural number and it turned out. It took 10 seconds. I wait your reaction.

Comment: @ONG SEE HAI HCI See my previous comment. I wait your reaction.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I guess your train of thought makes sense

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg see my solution for part 2, I think you missed out another root.

Comment: also, $x=1-\sqrt{2}$ serves as a potential solution to the equation in  problem $1$ too.

Comment: @ONG SEE HAI HCI I don't agree. The domain $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what @Michael Rozenberg is trying to say now. Basically, he views the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ as the point(s) of intersection between the two functions $y=g(x)$ and $y=f(x)$. For example, for the second problem, to solve $x^{x-x^2+13}=x^2-12$, he says that we are essentially finding the points of intersection of $2$ functions, $f(x)=x^{x-x^2+13}$ and $g(x)=x^2-12$. But under such an interpretation, we have to take the domains of the functions into consideration, which means that there might be solutions to the original solution that were being omitted.

So here's how to proceed: First note that $D_f=x \in \mathbb{R^+_{0}}$, and $D_g=\mathbb{R}.$ Now, $x^2-12=-(x-x^2+13)+x+1$, so let $x-x^2+13=A$. Thus, the original equation reduces to: $x^A=-A+x+1$, $x \geq 0$. Then, treating $A$ as a constant, we have the solution to this new equation to be $A=1$; this can be seen by inspection. It is easy to prove that no other values of $A$ will give us equality:

Let $h(x)=x^A+A-x-1,x\geq0$. When $x=A$, we have $h(x)=0$. Also, $h'(x)=Ax^{A-1}-1$. If $A>1$, $h'(x)=Ax^{A-1}-1 > x^{A-1}>x^0-1>0,$ where the second last inequality follows since $x$ is non-negative. Thus, $h(x)$ is strictly increasing and $\geq 0$ $\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R^+_{0}} \Rightarrow \ f(x)>g(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R^+_{0}}$. Likewise, if $A<1, h'(x)=Ax^{A-1}-1<x^{A-1}-1<x^0-1<0$ implies $h(x)$ is strictly decreasing and $ \leq 0$$\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R^+_{0}} \Rightarrow \ f(x)<g(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R^+_{0}}$.

Thus, given $A=1$, let $x-x^2+13=1 \Rightarrow x=-3 $ or $x=4$, but we reject the former solution since we have to take into account the domain of $f(x)$, $D_f$.